# Is there a way to get SAXParser to ignore content of certain elements when parsing?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have XML of the format:

```
...
<To>"Paul McCartney" <paul.mccartney@hotmail.com></To>
<From>"John Lennon" <john.lennon@yahoo.com></From>
...
```

The SAXParser throws an exception as soon as it gets to the email addresses. It thinks `<paul.mccartney@hotmail.com>` is an XML element and throws and exception as soon as it encounters the `@` symbol. Is there anyway to ignore content of certain elements in Java SAX?

Comment: There might be a workaround, but the basic problem is that the data is **not valid XML**! Whoever is producing it must fix it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try by overriding `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler.error()`, and similar methods, if you're using the DefaultHandler? See also the JavaDoc of `org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler`:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html

But in any way, the XML is invalid. It shouldn't be that way. You could preprocess it and replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;` or just wrap the whole `<To/>` and `<From/>` content into a `<![CDATA[ ]]>` block...

Comment: Tried overriding error handlers... That didn't help. But I think your CDATA suggestion is good. I'm actually talking about ActiveSync servers here... They send back all the data in <ApplicationData> elements, and what ever it contains, I could wrap around with CDATA. Thanks @Lukas :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not XML so an XML parser won't parse it, if you can get the format changed otherwise your best bet it to roll you own parser specific to this format.